# Pinescript/Tradingview: plot most recent horizontal line with lookback option

Tags: pine-script

I'd like to know how to show only most recent horizontal line at EMA Cross.
i tried looking into line.delete but i still have basic pinecoding experience.

below i'm able to plot line at emacross.
Thank you ! :)

```
//@version=4

study(title="ema buy sell", overlay=true)
ema5 = ema(close, 13)
ema13 = ema(close, 62)
cross = crossover(ema5, ema13)

plot(ema5, title="Take Long TP", color=color.red, linewidth=2, transp=0)
plot(ema13, title="Take Short TP", color=color.green, linewidth=1, transp=0)


var float lineOnCrossOver = na
if cross[1] != cross
    lineOnCrossOver := ema13
plot(lineOnCrossOver, color = change(lineOnCrossOver)? na : color.green)

var float lineOnCrossUnder = na
if crossunder(ema5, ema13)
    lineOnCrossUnder := ema13
plot(lineOnCrossUnder, color = change(lineOnCrossUnder)? na : color.red)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var line crossoverLine = line.new(x1 = na, y1 = na, x2 = na, y2 = na, xloc = xloc.bar_time, color = color.green, extend = extend.right)
var line crossunderLine = line.new(x1 = na, y1 = na, x2 = na, y2 = na, xloc = xloc.bar_time, color = color.red, extend = extend.right)

if crossover(ema5, ema13)
    line.set_xy1(crossoverLine, x = time[1], y = ema5)
    line.set_xy2(crossoverLine, x = time, y = ema5)

if crossunder(ema5, ema13)
    line.set_xy1(crossunderLine, x = time[1], y = ema5)
    line.set_xy2(crossunderLine, x = time, y = ema5)
```